# CURL download_progress throws SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, curl, libcurl

> I have to update the progress bar value in download_progress but it keeps sending segmented fault whenever I trys to update the member function of myClass
>   This is my Code:

```
class myClass{
    int percent;
    ProgressBar bar;
public:
    int download(const char* url, const char* filename, int enable_progress);
    int download_progress(void *p, double dl, double dlnow, double ul, double ulnow);

};

int myClass::download_progress(void *cli, double dl, double dlnow, double ul, double ulnow)
{
    double p = (dl / dlnow) * 100;
    myClass *mp = (myClass *)cli;

    mp->percent = (int)dl;
    mp->bar.setVal(p)

    return 0;
}

int myClass::download(const char* url, const char* filename)
{
    int res = 0;
    CURL* handle = curl_easy_init();
    if (handle == NULL) {
    return -1;
    }

    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!f) {
    return -1;
    }


    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, f);

    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, (curl_progress_callback)&myClass::download_progress);

    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "InetURL/1.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);

    curl_easy_perform(handle);
    curl_easy_cleanup(handle);

    off_t sz = ftello(f);
    fclose(f);

    if ((sz == 0) || (sz == (off_t)-1)) {
    res = -1;
    remove(filename);
    }

    return res;
}
```

---

> Trying to download file from url to filename but it keeps throwing SIGSEGV
>      Why I can not update members of myClass in the above code... 
>      any help will be appreciated
>
> ### Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First up you need to make

```
&myClass::download_progress
```

into a static function and call it simply as:

```
&download_progress
```

Comment: static function inside class?? or global

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending the userdata to be called. Your download method should be like this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, (curl_progress_callback)&myClass::download_progress);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, this);
```

Also, your download_progress should be marked as static:

```
class myClass{
    int percent;
    ProgressBar bar;
public:
    int download(const char* url, const char* filename, int enable_progress);
    static int download_progress(void *p, double dl, double dlnow, double ul, double ulnow);

};
```

Comment: progress Bar updates but it crash exe throwing this error:
*** Error in `/root/Desktop/test': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x00007fffd003f411 ***
@Bruno Ferreira

Comment: That problem is somewhere else.